# react hook form validation problem while i tried map inputs

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-hook-form

Good day everyone!. I'm trying use material ui library with React Hook Form on TS but faced with problem of display my validation form.
I used map for create 7 textfield(inputs)  but i cant display right result of validation

constants and types

```
    interface FormInputsType {
    name: string
    surname: string
    email: string
    password: string
    repeatPassword: string
    address: string
    phone: string
  }
   interface InputMapType {
    inputName: keyof FormInputsType
    label : string
    message: string
    validation?: string
  }
 const inputMap:InputMapType[] = [
  {
    label: 'name',
    inputName: 'name',
    message: 'the field name must be filled in',
  },
  {
    label: 'surname',
    inputName: 'surname',
    message: `the field surname must be filled in`,
  },
  {
    label: 'password',
    inputName: 'password',
    message: 'the field password must be filled in',
  },
  {
    label: 'confirm password',
    inputName: 'repeatPassword',
    message: 'the field confirm password must be filled in',
  },
  {
    label: 'adress',
    inputName: 'address',
    message: 'the field adress  must be filled in',
  },
  {
    label: 'phone',
    inputName: 'phone',
    message: 'the field phone must be filled in',
  },
  {
    label: 'Email',
    inputName: 'email',
    message: 'the field email must be filled in',
  }
]
```

code:

```
const {
    formState: { errors },
    handleSubmit,
    control,
  } = useForm<FormInputsType>()
  inputMap.map(({ label, inputName, message }, index) => {    
  })
  <Grid item xs={7}>
          {inputMap.map(({ label, inputName, message }, index) => (
            <div key={`input ${index}`}>
              <Controller 
                name={inputName}
                control={control}
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <TextField
                    label={label}
                    variant="outlined"
                    color="primary"
                    margin="normal"
                    fullWidth
                    {...field}
                  />
                )}
                rules={{
                  required: {
                    value: true,
                    message: message,
                  },
                }}
              />
              <Typography component="p" color="error">
                {errors.name?.message}
              </Typography>
            </div>
          ))}
          <Button
            className={classes.button}
            onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
            variant="contained"
            fullWidth={true}
          >
            Войти
          </Button>
        </Grid>
```

I have problem with display my error in

```
<Typography component="p" color="error">
   {errors.name?.message}
 </Typography>
```

I tried write {errors.inputName?.message
But i have proble with ts. "Property 'inputName' does not exist on type 'FieldErrorsImpl<DeepRequired>"

If i wrote errors.name?.message i will got "the field name must be filled in" for 7 times
Can someone say me how i can fix it?

Thank you for attention =)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass in your input name using array destructuring like this

```
<Typography component="p" color="error">
   {errors[inputName]}
 </Typography>
```

see the example below

```
  const InputData = [
    {
      title: "name",
      label: "Ticket Type",
      type: "text",
      placeholder: "Regular Ticket",
      errorMessage: "Ticket type must not be empty",
    },
    {
      title: "price",
      label: "Ticket Price",
      type: "number",
      placeholder: "0.0",
      errorMessage: "Price must not be empty",
    },
    {
      title: "qty",
      label: "Ticket Quantity",
      type: "number",
      placeholder: "Quantity",
      errorMessage: "Ticket Quantity must not be empty",
    },
  ];


<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row gap-7 w-full py-7 px-4 shadow-md rounded-sm">
            {InputData.map(
              ({ title, label, placeholder, type, errorMessage }, index) => (
                <div key={index} className="flex flex-col ">
                  {errors[title] && (
                    <p className="text-red-500">{errorMessage}</p>
                  )}
                  <label className="text-sm">{label}</label>
                  <input
                    className="outline-none border rounded-xs p-2 border-slate-300 bg-none my-2"
                    type={type}
                    placeholder={placeholder}
                    {...register(title, { required: true })}
                    variant="none"
                  />
                </div>
              )
            )}
          </div>
        </form>
```

this should work

Note that I defined my error message in the array of objects above then I returned each error based on the input title in the code snippet

```
{errors[title] && (
  <p className="text-red-500">{errorMessage}</p>
)}
```